# Google Analytics: Can't track overlay pages

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp, google-analytics, overlay

I'm trying to track product page views on a e-commerce site developed in CakePHP. Basically, there's a list of products, you click on a product and an overlay page pops up with the product.

The product page that pops up is a separate page and not a typical modal window (that is, the product page code does not reside on the parent page). I can actually open each product page up by itself. But on the list of products page, the product page pops up lightbox style.

So here's the problem: When I open a products page by itself, GA recognizes it. But when I open it on the product list page, it doesn't.

The GA code is installed in both the product list page and the product view page (which i can see using 'view source' when opening the page by itself). I'm using the latest universal analytics code.

The only thing I can think of is that the product list page is opening a modal window with the product page inside and somehow it's not firing the GA script, but I have no idea why or how to fix it.

**UPDATE:** So it turns out the site is using an old thickbox script.

http://codylindley.com/thickbox/

And, based on how it's being activated, it looks like whoever set it up is using the Ajax method. This suggests that the following solution should fix the problem.

[Tracking a page in an Ajax Popover from Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655093/tracking-a-page-in-an-ajax-popover-from-google-analytics)

However, this solution is for the older version of analytics. I've already upgraded to the newest version and I have no idea how to adjust this solution for the newest version.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Is the GA code actually executing when you open the product page by itself?

Comment: How does your modal window work ? E.g. jQuery can pull html fragments into a modal window (i.e. only  the contents of a specified DOM element), so it might be your analytics script is loaded when the page  is opened by itself but not when it's in the modal. In that case you'd need a virtual page tracking call in the function that opens the modal window.

Comment: First of all, sorry for the slow response. Even though I'm set up to receive response notifications, I'm not getting them so I thought no one responded.

Comment: See updated information in original question. 

 @lyyons, yes, the GA code does execute when by itself.